# Updating editText values to get sum or difference

Tags: android, addtextchangedlistener

I have multiple EditText fields in which I would like to update according to the data in each one, so I'm using `addTextChangedListener` for them. My goal is to get the sum of two EditText values and display the answer in another EditText. However, I'm also trying to get the difference of the third EditText and one of the first two to display in the first. So `amountreceived = totalprice + tip`, I want to update accordingly, as well as if the user entered data into the total price and amount received, I would like it to be `tip = amountreceived - totalprice`.

My code is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.order_details);

    eAmountReceived = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountReceived);
    eTotalCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.orderTotal);
    eTip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tip);
    eMileage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mileage);
    eGrandTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grandTotal);

    eAmountReceived.addTextChangedListener(this);
    eTip.addTextChangedListener(this);

    // eTotalCost.addTextChangedListener(this);
    // eMileage.addTextChangedListener(this);
    // eGrandTotal.addTextChangedListener(this);

    eTip.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after){}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count)
        {
            if(eTip.isFocused() && isSet(eAmountReceived) && isSet(eTotalCost))
            {
                updateSubtract();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){}
    });

    eAmountReceived.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after){}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count)
        {
            if(eAmountReceived.isFocused() && isSet(eTotalCost) && isSet(eTip))
            {
                updateAdd();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){}
    });
}

private void updateAdd()
{
    double dTotalCost = Double.valueOf(eTotalCost.getText().toString());
    double dTip = Double.valueOf(eTip.getText().toString());
    eAmountReceived.setText(String.valueOf(dTotalCost + dTip));
}

private void updateSubtract()
{
    double dAmountReceived = Double.valueOf(eAmountReceived.getText().toString());
    double dTotalCost = Double.valueOf(eTotalCost.getText().toString());
    eTip.setText(String.valueOf(dAmountReceived - dTotalCost));
}

private boolean isSet(EditText editText)
{
    return !editText.getText().toString().matches("");
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) 
{
    updateAdd();
    updateSubtract();
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}

public void onClick(View view)
{

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    orderTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.orderTotal);
    amountReceived = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountReceived);
    tip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tip);
    mileage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mileage);
    grandTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grandTotal);

    String cName = name.getText().toString();
    String num = number.getText().toString();
    String cAddress = address.getText().toString();
    String cOrderTotal = orderTotal.getText().toString();
    String cAmountReceived = amountReceived.getText().toString();
    String cTip = tip.getText().toString();
    String cMileage = mileage.getText().toString();
    String cGrandTotal = grandTotal.getText().toString();


    int id = db.addContact(new PhoneBook(cName, num, cAddress, cOrderTotal,
                                          cAmountReceived, cTip, cMileage, cGrandTotal));
    contactList.add(new PhoneBook(id, cName, num, cAddress, cOrderTotal,
                                   cAmountReceived, cTip, cMileage, cGrandTotal));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entry Successfully Created.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I thought this would work, but when I click on an EditText field to enter the data, the app crashes. I also have no errors in my logcat, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The logcat error is as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main


    Process: com.example.boley.databaseexample, PID: 2949
                            java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:338)
at com.example.boley.databaseexample.OrderDetails.updateAdd(OrderDetails.java:193)
at com.example.boley.databaseexample.OrderDetails.onTextChanged(OrderDetails.java:215)
at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7991)
at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:8053)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:10157)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1033)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:559)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:492)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:491)
at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:6098)
at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5911)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2640)
at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9234)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2395)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1727)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2725)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:543)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:53)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:315)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2310)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4127)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3820)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3981)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2253)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1874)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodMan
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no stack trace? This seems like a pretty simple app that should give a common exception. Maybe it can't find one of the id's you're trying to find in your xml layout

Comment: Actually, after exiting Android Studio and loading it back up, it does show the error. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here in the way you are parsing your double values

```
private void updateSubtract() {
    double dAmountReceived = Double.valueOf(eAmountReceived.getText().toString());
    double dTotalCost = Double.valueOf(eTotalCost.getText().toString());
    eTip.setText(String.valueOf(dAmountReceived - dTotalCost));
}
```

If you change `updateSubtract()` and `updateAdd()` to something like this it should solve your problem. I just wrote this without testing but I'm sure it should be fine.

```
private void updateSubtract() {
    String amountReceivedText = eAmountReceived.getText().toString();
    String totalCostText = eTotalCost.getText().toString();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(amountReceivedText) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(totalCostText)) {}
        float dAmountReceived = Float.parseFloat(amountReceivedText);
        float dTotalCost = Float.parseFloat(totalCostText);
        float dTipValue = dAmountReceived - dTotalCost;
        eTip.setText(String.valueOf(dTipValue));
    }
}
```

You should also make sure that you either check the input of `eAmountReceived` and `totalCostText`to make sure it is a `Float` value or apply a inputType on your `EditText` so that it only takes float values as input. I prefer the latter because it gives you a numbers only keyboard when you focus on the `EditText`.

Comment: This way seems to cause the app to crash as well, but this time I don't get any errors in my logcat. I can input data into the totalcost EditText, but once I start inputting data in the tip or amount received EditText, the app crashes. It must be something on my end, because I've had people try to help me, but nothing works for some reason.

Comment: Did you change updateAdd? The error you got previously was on that method

Comment: I did the same thing as updateSubtract, but used string variables totalCostText and tipText. And then used float values dAmountReceived, dTotalCost, and dTipValue.